# Uploading to Amazon S3 using a signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, postman

I'm implementing a file uploading functionality that would be used by an angular application. But I am having numerous issues getting it to work. And need help figuring out what I am missing. Here is an overview of the resources in place, and the testing and results I'm getting.

**Infrastructure**

- I have an Amazon S3 bucket created with versioning enabled, encryption enabled and all public access is blocked.
- An API gateway with a Lambda function that generates a pre-signed URL. The code is shown below.

```
    def generate_upload_url(self):
        try:
            conditions = [
                {"acl": "private"},
                ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]
            ]
            fields = {"acl": "private"}
            response = self.s3.generate_presigned_post(self.bucket_name,
                                                       self.file_path,
                                                       Fields=fields,
                                                       Conditions=conditions,
                                                       ExpiresIn=3600)
        except ClientError as e:
            logging.error(e)
            return None
        return response
```

- The bucket name and file path are set as part of the class constructor. In this example the bucket and file path are

```
    def construct_file_names(self):
        self.file_path = self.account_number + '-' + self.user_id + '-' + self.experiment_id + '-experiment-data.json'
        self.bucket_name = self.account_number + '-' + self.user_id + '-resources'
```

**Testing via Postman**

Before implementing it within my angular application. I am testing the upload functionality via Postman.

- The response from my API endpoint for the pre-signed URL is shown below

[image]

- Using these values, I make another API call from Postman and receive the response below

[image]

If anybody can see what I might be doing wrong here. I have played around with different fields in the boto3 method, but ultimately, I am getting 403 errors with different messages related to Policy conditions. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update 1**

- I tried to adjust the order of "file" and "acl" but received another error shown below

[image]

**Update Two - Using signature v4**

- I updated the pre-signed URL code, shown below

```
def upload_data(x):
    try:
        config = Config(
            signature_version='s3v4',
        )
        s3 = boto3.client('s3', "eu-west-1", config=config)
        sts = boto3.client('sts', "eu-west-1")
        data_upload = UploadData(x["userId"], x["experimentId"], s3, sts)
        return data_upload.generate_upload_url()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
```

- When the Lambda function is triggered by the API call, the following is received by Postman

[image]

- Using the new key values returned from the API, I proceeded to try another test upload. The results are shown below

[image]

Once again an error but I think I'm going in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `acl` above the `file` row. Make sure `file` is at the end.

Comment: when I adjust the order, I get another error message. Ill add it above.

Comment: @hynespm use `s3v4`. `var s3 = new AWS.S3({signatureVersion: 'v4'});`

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working, so I will post an answer here summarising the steps taken.

**Python Code for generating pre-signed URL via boto in eu-west-1**

- Use signature v4 signing  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html

```
def upload_data(x):
    try:
        config = Config(
            signature_version='s3v4',
        )
        s3 = boto3.client('s3', "eu-west-1", config=config)
        sts = boto3.client('sts', "eu-west-1")
        data_upload = UploadData(x["userId"], x["experimentId"], s3, sts)
        return data_upload.generate_upload_url()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)

    def generate_upload_url(self):
        try:
            conditions = [
                {"acl": "private"},
                ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]
            ]
            fields = {"acl": "private"}
            response = self.s3.generate_presigned_post(self.bucket_name,
                                                       self.file_path,
                                                       Fields=fields,
                                                       Conditions=conditions,
                                                       ExpiresIn=3600)
        except ClientError as e:
            logging.error(e)
            return None
        return response
```

**Uploading  via Postman**

- Ensure the order is correct with "file" being last
- Ensure "Content-Type" matches what you have in the code to generate the URL. In my case it was "". Once added, the conditions error received went away.

[image]

**S3 Bucket**

- Enable a CORS policy if required. I needed one and it is shown below, but this link can help - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

**Upload via Angular**

My issue arose during testing with Postman, but I was implementing the functionality to be used by an Angular application. Here is a code snippet of how the upload is done by first calling the API for the pre-signed URL, and then uploading directly.

[image]

**Summary**

- Check your S3 infrastructure
- Enable CORS if need be
- Use sig 4 explicitly in the SDK of choice, if working in an old region
- Ensure the form data order is correct

Hope all these pieces help others who are trying to achieve the same. Thanks for all the hints from SO members.